# Visualize the Results of GridSearchCV [sklearn]

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to visualize the results (i.e. the `mean score` and the `params`) of a `GridSearchCV`.

I've found a solution if you have 2 parameter to adjust:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_compare_reduction.html

But my problem is that I currently have **3 parameters**, so this kind of visualization won't work. Does someone have an idea how to visualize it? Is there a good way to visualize it regardless how many parameters are there? (1,2,3,4 parameters ...)

At the moment I just print the results like this:

```
for mean, params in zip(grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score'], grid.cv_results_['params']):
      print("%0.3f for %r" % (mean, params))
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your result to dataframe and then use pandas scatter_matrix (or something similar from matplotlib) to visualize it.

You can apply color or/and size to your objective function.

Below not exactly working example, but some code to give an idea:

```
cmb['rgb'] = scale(cmb[msr_col], 1, 0.25)      
cmb['size'] = scale( (cmb[msr_col] * cmb[msr_col]), 100, 1000)
df = pd.concat([cmb.seed, cmb.bk_val_profit_brutto_prc, cmb.bk_val_profit_brutto, cmb.recall_pos_val, cmb.target_col, cmb.return_over, cmb.max_depth_], axis=1)
ms = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.50, figsize=figsize_, diagonal='hist', c=cmb['rgb'], s=cmb['size'])
```

Comment: It's a nice idea and I have plotted it: https://s29.postimg.org/v6y1gatrb/scatterplot.png
But it's really hard to read, I think. Especially because there are also useless information. For example comparing two parameters is always a grid (that's the nature of the GridSearchCV). Any idea to improve this?

Comment: According to the plot you get higher accuracy when k_best is high (1000) and max features (1200), but you have to look at you minimum as well. You use different seeds for GridSearch ? It's a good idea to show them on the plot to see how model behaves for different splits